# Resource files not loaded properly in the silverlight client

Tags: silverlight, iis, silverlight-4.0

I have a SL 4.0 application hosted on IIS with a possibility to change GUI language. The problem is that hosted on one machine , language functionality works and on the other machine not. Inside this piece of code:

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(message.NewCulture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(message.NewCulture);
```

on Windows7 it does update UICulture with correct resource file and on Windows Server 2008 it does not. IIS settings on both systems seem to be the same. Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: When you mention Windows Server 2008, are you running locally on the server or is Windows Server 2008 hosting the web application and you're running it from a client machine?

Comment: @Kevin -Windows Server is hosting the app and I'm running it from separate machine (which has Windows server or Windows 7 as operating system, tried on different browsers)

Comment: The culture used is based on the client's computer/browser setting. I wasn't clear from your question if you're running your code sample on the client (in SL). I thought it might be possible that you had the code in the wrong spot (ie the server). It seems like you do, but a bit more in your code snippet could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Blog entry made by Tim Heuer on the subject.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx

Using this blog post, I was able to get Globalization/Localization implemented in a short amount of time and minimal effort.

It sounds like you need to take a look at the Access Modifier section in the designer.  You'll need to set this to Public in order to use it in XAML binding. Also check that all the RESX files are marked as Embedded Resource in the properties for the files.

Additionally make sure your string resource dictionaries have extensions to something similar:
[image]

P.S. I hope you'll read Tim's blog entry, he goes into a lot more detail than what I've explained. Also from my personal experience, I wasn't able to dynamically reload the language on the fly until I took a look the section on the blog post titled "Public modifier workaround and dynamically setting the culture".

Comment: thx but I build my localization using that Blog entry :) However, I've made some changes later but the core remained the same. Unfortunately nothing helped, still on some machines localization works perfectly and on other it fails. Anyway, +1 for Blog entry which I have almost forgotten

Answer (score 0):

R-Click the assembly(ies) containing your localized files, select unload project and then edit the project file(s). The project files are in XML format. Look for a XML tag related to SupportedCultures (or something like that). Make sure that your cultures are in the list.

Localization didn't want to kick in for me until I got that resolved.

Comment: thx for suggestion but I have already done it a couple of times